# React Router implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i'm new to **ReactJS** and i'm learning how to use **react-router** for routing, but the [react-router documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/latest/docs) has only been a source to my frustration, so i have to go elsewhere to understand it.

This is my code:

```
ReactDOM.render((
        <ReactRouter>
            <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
                <ReactRouter.Route path="create" component={CreateRecipe} />
                <ReactRouter.Route path=":id" component={ShowRecipe}>
                    <ReactRouter.Route path="edit" component={EditRecipe} />
                    <ReactRouter.Route path="delete" component={DeleteRecipe} />
                </ReactRouter.Route>
            </ReactRouter.Route>
        </ReactRouter>
    ), document.getElementById("app-container"));
```

But when loaded on the browser i get the following error in my browser's console.

> **Warning:** React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).

Please what could be the cause and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Routes should be wrapped inside a Router, so `<ReactRouter>` should be `<ReactRouter.Router>`.

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <ReactRouter.Router>
        <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
            <ReactRouter.Route path="create" component={CreateRecipe} />
            <ReactRouter.Route path=":id" component={ShowRecipe}>
                <ReactRouter.Route path="edit" component={EditRecipe} />
                <ReactRouter.Route path="delete" component={DeleteRecipe} />
            </ReactRouter.Route>
        </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>
), document.getElementById("app-container"));
```

If you want to clean your code, you can replace all yours `ReactRouter.Router` by `Router` and `ReactRouter.Route` by `Route`, then adapt your code:

```
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;  
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
```

I suggest you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6Kczrgw6ic) from [Michael Jackson](https://github.com/mjackson) if you're struggling with the doc to grasp what you can do with react-router and a few examples.

Comment: Note that a lot has changed in version 4 of react-router.