# i write a react demo Using react-router,why the ticket route is null? the react-router-dom version is 4.2.2

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i write a react demo 
Using react-router,why the ticket route is null?  the react-router-dom version is 4.2.2.

```
<Router history={ReactHistory}>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={counter}/>
                    <Route path="/Ticket" component={test}/>
                </div></Router>
```

the ticket route is null React Developer Tools.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, it's best to post the relevant code (as code, not images) so we can see, or replicate the issue. Here's a [great explanation of how to write a great question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you give us more code examples on how you defined this route in the router itself?

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511782/react-router-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Try to exchange *div* element inside the router with *Switch* e.g.

```
import { Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// render section
return (
  <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        ... your routes
      </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```